# Show that the following statements characterize the straight line as curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

(1) All tangent lines to the curve pass through a fixed point

(2) All tangent lines are pallalel to a given line

(3) $k = 0$ ($k$ is the curvature)

(4) The curve $\alpha(t)$ satisfies $\alpha'(t)$ and $\alpha''(t)$ being linearly independent

This question is from the book "[Geometry from a differentiable viewpoint](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=O9P8Rd8Klw0C&redir_esc=y)". I have some geometrial arguments for proving the result above, but I fear they're not "geometric differential" arguments, but geometric only, so they'll not be accepted by my teacher. For example, I know that a line $l$ is parametrized as:

$l = (a,b,c) + \lambda(e,d,f)$

where $(a,b,c)$ is a point of the line, and $(e,d,f)$ is a direction vector.

The derivative of this, gives the constant direction vector $(e,d,f)$, which when derived again, gives the $0$ vector. So they're linearly independent, right? (4) is proved?

Can I say that all tangent lines are parallel to $(e,d,f)$, and therefore, parallel to a given line (a line with $(e,d,f)$ as direction vector). Therefore (2) is proved.

What about (1)? I cannot understand what it's saying. What does it means to a tangent line pass through a fixed point?

Comment: In (4) you should have "linearly dependent" (and this also is what you show is true).

Comment: Condition (1) is not on one tangent line, it means that there is one point, in which all tangent lines intersect.